# Finding dimension of orthogonal complement

Tags: orthogonality, trace, bilinear-form

The question goes as follows:

> Let there be $\xi \in T_2(V)$ Where $V = M_n(\mathbb C))$:
>
> $\xi (A,B) = n*tr(AB)-tr(A)tr(B).$
>
> Find $dim(V_{\bot\xi})$.
>
> $( V_{\bot\xi} = \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb C) | \xi(A,B) = 0, \forall B\in M_n(\mathbb C) \})$

I was struggling to find the dimension, this is what I tried to do:

First we mark $A=(a_{ij}), B = (b_{ij})$.
Then, we want to find all $A \in M_n\mathbb C$ that $n*tr(Ab)=tr(A)tr(B)$ for every $B\in  M_n\mathbb C$.

Since $tr(AB) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ji}$, we get that:

$$n * \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ji} = \sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}*\sum_{j=1}^nb_{jj}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n na_{ij}b_{ji} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ii}b_{jj}$$
but I don't know how to continue from here. Am I on the right track? Is there any other intuitive way?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful to say explicitly that $V_{\perp \xi}$ is the kernel of the map $V \to V^*$, $A \mapsto \xi(A, \,\cdot\,)$?

Comment: @Travis I've updated the question for more clarification

Comment: Pick a basis $(E_{ab})$ of $M_n(\Bbb C)$ (the standard one works well), and compute $\xi(A, E_{ab})$ for all basis elements $E_{ab}$.

Comment: @Travis, thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Let $(E^a{}_b)$ denote the standard basis of $M_n(\Bbb C)$. The condition implies the $n^2$ conditions $$\xi(A, E^a{}_b) = 0 .$$ Write these conditions in terms of the entries of $A$.

Comment: ok, what I get is by for every $E_{ii}$, I get that $\xi(A,E_{ii}) = na_{ii} - tr(A)$, and for every $E_{ij}$ where $i\neq j$ I get that $\xi(A,E_{ij}) = 0$. Therefore all $A$ such that the diagonal is the same  scalar, and everything else must be zero, is in the kernel? meaning the dimension is $1$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Put another way, the kernel is the span of the identity map. There is, by the way, a natural reason to consider the particular bilinear form $\xi$ in the first plate: If we regard $M_n(\Bbb C)$ as a Lie algebra by defining the Lie bracket to be the usual commutator, the map $\xi$ is (up to an overall constant) the *Killing form* of the Lie algebra. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form